# extjs column sort & sort arrow icon

Tags: sorting, extjs, extjs4, columnheader

I have a list of projects. When I click on a column header, the column is sorted and a sort arrow icon appears in the column header. However, the column keeps the sort and the sort arrow icon even after filtering the records (by entering text in the filter textfield and pressing the Filter button). I want the sort and the sort arrow icon to be removed from the column each time I filter the records. I have found some posts about clearing the sort arrow icon when a grid reloads (see links below). But how can I apply this to my situation? Any tips would be much appreciated.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?48437-Help-How-to-remove-sort-field-when-reload-grid

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?3098-Clear-grid-s-sort-arrow-icon

Comment: These solutions are for Ext 2.x what version of Ext are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ext JS 4.x you can just clear the sorters on the grid before you filter.

```
grid.store.sorters.clear();
grid.store.filter("name", "Lisa");
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/5aKdc/

UPDATE:

if you don't filter/make a change you can force the UI to update by using:

```
grid.view.refresh();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/5aKdc/3/

Comment: I do have a question though. I have place the line of code (grid.store.sorters.clear();) in the handler function of the Clear Filter button. Now if there is a filter present and I sort one column,pressing the Clear Filter button will not only remove the filter it will also remove the sort and the sort arrow icon from the column and column header. However, if there is no filter present and I click the Clear Filter button after clicking sort on a column, the sort and the sort arrow icon is NOT removed from the column and column header. How to ensure that even in this case the sorter is cleared?

Comment: the filtering (or changing of the filtering) updates the UI so you could trigger a UI update (I'll update my answer with code in a moment :) )

Answer (score 0):

**Use following options at column model (ExtJs 3.4)**

```
menuDisabled:true //there will be no any menu 
sortable:false // there will be menu but disabled sorting option
```